# Is it possible to use some kind of filter in the source property of a field or input?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to use a much more complex `source` property than any examples I have seen. Both for fields and inputs. Instead of displaying a simple field, I want to select a particular field from a list in the source. More explanation below, but I like to be able to have a source more complex than even this:

```xml
<TextField source="translations[language = 'en'].title" label="Title" />
```

I have the following JSON for my input:

```js
{ "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "translations": [
      { "language": "en", "title": "English" },
      { "language": "ar", "title": "Arabic" }
    ]
  }
}
```

This comes in from a GraphQL source, which does not have dicts. So that's why `translations` is a list of records. In my Datagrid I want to display the English title if it exists, else the Arabic title.

I can use things like:

```xml
<Datagrid>
  <TextField source="translations[0].title" label="Title" />
</Datagrid>
```

However I would like to write something like:

```xml
<Datagrid>
  <TextField source="translations[language = 'en'].title" label="Title" />
</Datagrid>
```

And obviously more complex. I suppose I need to be able to call my own function to have exactly the logic I want. Is this possible, and how?

Another solution would be to transform the GraphQL derived JSON into a proper dict/hash before react-admin handles this so I can write:

```xml
<TextField source="translations['en'].title" label="Title" />
```

But this would mean I have to do that on the create/update side then again, but that's fine. Not sure this works, as I use `ra-data-graphql-simple`.

Comment: I discovered that the source property is a string, so it won't take a function.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I need to create my own field, that seems to work best:

```js
const TitleField = props => {
    const { record } = props
    let titleIndex = 0
    record.law_texts.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.language === "ar")
            titleIndex = index
    })
    const source = "law_texts[" + titleIndex + "].title"
    return <TextField {...props} source={source}/>
};
```

and then use that field.